# Installation of Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: oracle, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I have been struggling to install Oracle 11g Express Edition on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS version.

I have followed these steps:

1. Downloaded 11g express edition from Oracle's [site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html)
2. Created a new user 'oracle' under the group dba. Following steps are executed using this.
3. unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip and then Converted the rpm to the Ubuntu package

   ```
   sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
   ```
4. Created `/sbin/chkconfig` file and added the entries as specified [here](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html?showComment=1357195285714#c4393074524447658792)
5. Created `/etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf` and added the entries as specified in same link as above.
6. Below steps:

   - `ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk`
   - `mkdir /var/lock/subsys`
   - `touch /var/lock/subsys/listener`
7. `sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb` (.deb generated in step 3)
8. `sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure` (left the default values as it is)
9. Set the following env variables in `~/.bashrc` file

   ```
   export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
   export ORACLE_SID=XE
   export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
   export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
10. Below  steps:

    ```
    chown -R oracle:dba /var/tmp/.oracle
    chmod -R 755 /var/tmp/.oracle
    chown -R oracle:dba /tmp/.oracle
    chmod -R 755 /tmp/.oracle
    ```
11. `sudo service oracle-xe start` (I didn't see any issues in this step)

12 . sqlplus / as sysdba and got the following

> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jan 3 09:41:58 2013
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> **Connected to an idle instance.**

Now when exectute any SQL statements on SQLplus, i end up with the following error

```
SQL> select * from dual;
select * from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I have increased the swap memory as specified in [here](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2011/09/installing-1-gb-swap-without.html)

---

```
 free -m
```

---

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1652       1596         56          0         53       1356
-/+ buffers/cache:        186       1466
Swap:         2943          0       2943
```

Can you guide me here? I am clueless.

Comment: did you really point the env variables as mentioned in step 9 to `/bashrc`? If so it's wrong

Comment: I have added the variables mentioned in step 9 to .bashrc. What went wrong?

Comment: You mention you've added them to `/bashrc`, not `~/.bashrc`. The two are not the same and the former is not read when starting a new shell

Comment: Sorry about that, its indeed ~/.bashrc. Updated step 9.

Comment: I ran startup from SqlPlus (_SQL> startup_) and got the following error

**ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/initXE.ora'**

So tried _SQL> startup pfile='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/init.ora';_

**ORA-48108: invalid value given for the diagnostic_dest init.ora parameter
ORA-48140: the specified ADR Base directory does not exist [/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/<ORACLE_BASE>]
ORA-48187: specified directory does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory**

Comment: These did the trick

sudo rm -rf /dev/shm

sudo mkdir /dev/shm

sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, after a day long struggle

These did the trick.

```
sudo rm -rf /dev/shm
sudo mkdir /dev/shm
sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm
```

Make sure that these are executed before the database is configured.

Comment: This unexpectedly shutdown my browser (chrome only, firefox remained open) and I wasn't able to open it until running `sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm`.